# Proving that a ratio between two functions is decreasing

Tags: limits, derivatives, convex-analysis

I have a question that seems to be easy, but I haven't been able to prove it. Any help would be appreciated:

> Let $f,g\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)>0$, $f(x)\geq0$, $f''(x)\leq0$, $\forall x$ and $g(0)=0$, $g(x)\geq0$, $g'(x)\geq0$, $g''(x)\geq0$, $\forall x$. 
>   Prove that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is decreasing.

I tried to use the property that say: if $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}$ then $\frac{a+c}{b+d}<\frac{c}{d}$. I used it with the fact that $f(x)=f(0)+\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f'(\frac{ix}{n})\frac{x}{n}$ . With this two elements I can prove that if $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(0)}{g(0)}$ exists,, then the solution is true. However, I haven't been able to prove it for the general case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One must specify that $g(x) \neq 0$ for $f/g$ to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given information, we know that $f$ is positive and concave and $g$ is positive and convex. For any $0 < y < x$, let $y=tx$.  Then $0<t<1$. From the concavity of $f$, we have

$$tf(x)+(1-t)f(0) \le f(tx) = f(y)$$ Since $f(0)=0$, that means $$tf(x) \le f(y)$$ Likewise, the convexity of $g$ gives  $$tg(x) \ge g(y)$$ Dividing the two inequalities above and defining $r(x) \equiv \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, we get $$r(x) \le r(y)$$ That is, $r$ is decreasing.

Comment: I think this solution is very neat. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that
$$D\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)=\frac{h(x)}{g^2(x)}$$
where $h(x):=f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)$,
and, by the given conditions,
$$h(0)=0,\quad h'(x)=f''(x)g(x)-f(x)g''(x)\leq 0\quad\text{for $x\geq 0$}.$$